# Is Electron decay period less than stated?

Tags: energy, particle-physics, electrons, gamma-rays

Phys. Rev. Lett. 115, 231802 – Published 3 December 2015 sets a limit on the stability of the electron for decay into a neutrino and a single monoenergetic photon in $\tau\ge6.6\ 10^{28}\ \mathrm{yr}$.

Given an electron and a positron, each with a mass of $0.511\ \mathrm{MeV}/c^2$, they can annihilate to yield 2 gamma rays with energy $1.022\ \mathrm{MeV}$. Is this not the decay of an electron and indicative of cosmological processes involving gamma ray bursts?

Comment: The decay does not conserve charge, the annihilation does. They are two completely different processes and none of that has anything to do with gamma ray bursts.

Comment: Put into the language of reaction you are asking is $e^- \longrightarrow \nu_e + \gamma$ is the same as $e^- + e^+ \longrightarrow \gamma + \gamma$. Are you sure that you need to ask?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is "no." Electron-positron annihilation is not "the decay of each" into single gamma rays plus a neutrino and an antineutrino. One straightforward reason is "then, where do the neutrinos go?" -- you could have them annihilate too, but then we would have four photons, not just two.

Comment: I quoted the Physics Review to draw attention to specific experiments done in Italy under Earth's gravity which restates dogma that electrons don't decompose. The question sought to highlight the different gravitational environments for 'annihilation events' to happen. Restated the question is -  "does the annihilation of positron/electron pairs constitute a reversal of the second law of thermodynamics and if not why is it not the decay of an electron ?"  Feynman diagrams for annihilation do not include neutrinos so why equate two separate processes ?

Comment: @ElevenD It is not the decay of an electron because it is two particles annihilating. It's rather like how if two cars smash into each other we would not describe that as both cars "decaying" independently -- no, they interacted. The only reason I included neutrinos is because you seemed to think that the article was relevant to your question. If you think "gravitational environments" have anything to do with any of this you're mistaken.

Comment: Quite the reverse, the physics community seems to think neutrinos could be involved in a decay process (http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/206418/108888 ) which might point to a decay period less than the age of the universe. Disregarding the gravity environment overlooks any observations of 'interactions' (car crashes in your analogy) in the cosmological environment. The real question is why two photons in the annihilation and no sign of an antiparticle. Without gravity, Majorana particles can solve anything.

Comment: @ElevenD Again, not a "decay process" -- and not relevant.

Comment: I am given to understand that the early universe had a similar ratio of hydrogen/helium as is observed today and that this coincides pretty much with the composition of main sequence stars. I am told that during the fusion process about 8.2% of the mass is lost as positron/electron annihilation. As an ongoing process in accordance with the second law of thermodynamics, does this not constitute electron decay ?

Comment: @ElevenD: It does not, in the common usage of that word.